# How to trigger different image base on input-box?

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have 2 images

The first one look like this 
[image]
and second one like this 
[image]
**GOAL**

- The first image load as `default` when the user land my my site
- When user start to type in their `username` OR `password` , I want to load the second image instead at the `exact` position of first image was placed.

How do I do that ?

Will I need to use `JS` to get this done ?

---

`EDIT`

- I want to show the image a moment the focus is on one of the 2 inputs
- Even if the user delete all letters in the textbox but as long as he/she is at the input field. 
  I want to trigger the 2nd image.

Huge `thanks` to all of you who involve in this post and your consideration !

Comment: No can do from what I know using css only, since the change is a result of an event.

Comment: You most probably will need `JS` and I suggest you to use `jQuery` for this. One approach is to just the `clcik` event of the `input` attribute. But there are several questions - do you care if there is a letter written in the textbox or you want to show the image the moment the focus is on one of the two inputs. Also, if you want a letter written, do you want the old image back if the user delete all letters in the textbox while he's there?

Comment: @Leron : I Edited my post base on your question. Please check it out !

Comment: @evoque2015 check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/vjq3aubd/ . Do you want something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is exactly what you mean - right ?

[**SOLUTION**](http://jsfiddle.net/0esjvv46/14/)

`JS`

```
$("#image2").hide();

$('#username').on('input', function (event) {
    $("#image1").hide();
    $("#image2").show();

});

$('#password').on('input', function (event) {
    $("#image1").hide();
    $("#image2").show();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this http://jsfiddle.net/tv0kgq6h/

html

```
<div id="first" style="position: absolute; top:0px;left: 0px;">
    <input class="txt1" type="text" />
    <br>
    <input class="txt1" type="password"/>
     <br>
    <input type="button" value="submit"/>
</div>
<div id="second"  style="position: absolute; top:0px;left: 0px;display:none">
    <input type="text" />
    <br>
    <input type="password"/>
     <br>
    <input type="button" value="submit2"/>
</div>
```

js

```
$(".txt1").click(function(){
$("#fist").hide();
  $("#second").show();
});
```

Comment: I didn't see any image involve in your JSFiddle. Can you use this   [1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jVpQf.png), and 
  [2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/0pfKH.png) in your code. Do you mind fix it ? Then I will make sure to accept your answer if it's work !!!

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javascript in order to change the image.
But if you change dynamically the image "src" attribute – or the background-image if not an img – you will see a little blink during transition.

For a clean effect you can use the [sprite technique](http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/).

Comment: Ohh .. nice.. I didn't think of that. You guys are awesome.

Answer (score 0):

You will need javascript and/or the JQuery library to make what you want to do happen.

Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/larryjoelane/0esjvv46/

If right click on the img elements and click on inspect element you will see in the
html that the src attributes will have changed.

Below is some basic html to get you started.

```
<img id = "image1" src="pathToImage1" alt ="1st Image">

<input type="text" id="username" value ="">

 <input type="text" id="password" value ="">

 <img id = "image2" src="pathToImage2" alt ="2nd Image">
```

JQuery you will need to change the img element src attribute:

```
    $("#username").on("change",function(){//begin on change event



    //replace the #image1 img element src with the #img2 element src
    $("#image1").attr("src",$("#image2").attr("src"));



});//end on change event



  $("#password").on("change",function(){//begin on change event



    //replace the #image1 img element src with the #img2 element src
    $("#image1").attr("src",$("#image2").attr("src"));



});//end on change event
```